# Python what code convention splitting arguments into lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

What is this convention of splitting arguments into lines? Is there a PEP that sanctions this? I did not find it in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
file_like = f(self,
              path,
              mode=mode,
              buffering=buffering,
              encoding=encoding,
              errors=errors,
              newline=newline,
              line_buffering=line_buffering,
              **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for the (A) [**Vertical Alignment**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) to be used when (B) Max Line Length will get exceeded, and sometimes even if it won't - for better readability.

These are the first 3 examples on that page illustrating it:

> Yes:
>
> ```
> # Aligned with opening delimiter.
> foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
>                          var_three, var_four)
>
> # More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
> def long_function_name(
>         var_one, var_two, var_three,
>         var_four):
>     print(var_one)
>
> # Hanging indents should add a level.
> foo = long_function_name(
>     var_one, var_two,
>     var_three, var_four)
> ```

The one you asked about is a **variation of the first example above, with only one arg per line for clarity**.

> No:
>
> ```
> # Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment.
> foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
>     var_three, var_four)
> ```

And (C), the arguments with the name given (keyword arguments) is done so that you don't need to lookup what the parameters are in the called function. Typically, every non-obvious parameter which may act like a flag or modifier to the core functionality of the called function should be passed as a keyword argument. Ex:

```
> read_file('abc.txt', 1024, True)  # yes, you know 'abc.txt' is the filename
> # What are the 1024 and True for?
> # versus...
> read_file('abc.txt', max_lines=1024, output_as_list=True)  # now you know what it does.
```

PS: [The answer by @falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192044/1431750) isn't wrong. Max line length is the first reason to re-format your code. As for the specific reason to align it that way, that's vertical alignment.

Comment: I know the OP didn't ask about (C) but I've added that anyway as an obvious "also fyi" for readers.

Answer (score 3):

[`Maximum Line Length`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length): If it was not splitted into multiple lines, the line length would be more than 79 characters.

Comment: PEP8 already shows few examples how calls should be broken apart, few arguments per line. This explanation is not satisfactory.

Comment: @ArekBulski: So what's you actually want?

Comment: @KevinGuan I think he is asking why there is one parameter per line instead of as many parameters as will fit before blowing past the 79th column.

Comment: @Turn: Hmm...however, I think this is more readable and clear, as aneroid's answer says.

Comment: @KevinGuan _I_ agree with you, I was just speculating as to what the OP was looking for. It is true that PEP8 doesn't seem to specify one way or the other.

Comment: I think it usually looks nicer to go 1 per line all all in the 1 line under 79 characters most times.